# help on wordpress for send mailling

Tags: wordpress, civimail, mosaico

I want to send mailling with civcrm and it doesn t work

i resume : 
i install wordpress, i install civcrm for wordpress extension and i install mosaico extension too
ok no problem

in wordpress -> i try to send a mail : Menu > contacts > New mail ... it's ok no problems the mail be sended
but when i try : menu : Mailings > New Mailing ... don't work

can you explain me the process please

thanks

Comment: The "contacts » new mail" approach does not use Mosaico.  "Mailings » New Mailing" does.  However, we can't help you if you don't tell us what the error you're seeing is.

Comment: ok i create a new message : Mailings > New Mailing I put 1 group with 1 individual contact for testing I complete :
Mailing Name, Template, from, récipients, Subject
and the content .... i try Send test email to and Send test email to group and i test to send the mailling immediatly and i test again with date ... I receive no email :'( I have two errors messages
first message (orange alert) :
**Could not identify any recipients. Perhaps the group is empty?** I don't understand because for my test I create 1 group with 1 individual contact 2nd alert (red color) Cron Not Running the second messa

Comment: Yes would be great to know what error you get to see if you have the same problem as me https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20657/syntax-error-from-civimail. But I'm not using mosaico and I'd be wary of that. Some of the components are only in alpha and I suspect its mainly been tested with Drupal and not WordPress.

Comment: OK now all is allright, i put Bounce Processing  in my mail account option (administer / civimail/mails accounts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention installing the Mosaico extension - assuming you're installing Mosaico 2.0, you also need to install the FlexMailer and Shoreditch extensions.  Please install those and try again.

Comment: Thks for your answers, 
i install flexmailer and Shoreditch right now and i test, i 'll go back ti say what 's happen (sorry for my English i'm french)